# Accessing input box under inner div

Tags: jquery

I have 4 such div's in my html file which represents 4 different rows of AWB No, HAWB No and Ref No
For each of them, I want to get the field with the id mawbNumber and perform some operation.
I'm trying access its value by using jquery each() but unable to do so.

```
<div class="row awb-box">
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <label class="inpt-lbl">AWB NO</label>
      <input type="text" id="mawbNumber" class="mAWBs" placeholder="AWB NO" maxlength="13"/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <label class="inpt-lbl">HAWB NO</label>
      <input type="text" id="hawbNumber" placeholder="HAWB NO"/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <label class="inpt-lbl">NFD REF.NO</label>
      <input type="text" id="refNumber" class="refNos" placeholder="NFD REF.NO" value="" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <label class="inpt-lbl">&nbsp;</label>
      <span class="plusbtn float-left"></span>
      <span class="spnerrorinfo float-left" style="display: none" id="error1"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

here is my jQuery:

```
$(".row.awb-box").each(function(){
    var  awb = $(this).child(3).find('mAWBs');
});
```

Comment: There's no `.child()` method in jQuery. There's `.children()`, but the argument is a selector, not a number.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `.child()` method. Just use `$(this).find()`. You also need the `.` in the `mAWBs` class selector.

```
$(".row.awb-box").each(function(){
    var  awb = $(this).find('.mAWBs');
    ...
});
```

You could also just combine the selectors:

```
$(".row.awb-box .mAWBs").each(function() {
    var awb = $(this);
    ...
});
```